# css/html, how to scale and center a logo image

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to create a typical main menu screen for a game. It's got a logo, centered at the top, and some menu buttons. It will always be shown in landscape layout and it needs to support different resolutions.

here's what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/L3mNT/

My questions are these:

1) Is it possible to **center and scale** the logo **using only DIV**? Or is it okay to "resort" to using the img-tag and center-tags? What are the (dis)advantages of a DIV? The DIV logo does scale when I tried adding a height in pixels, like so

```
.logo{
    ..
    height:120px;
}
```

but that would have to be updated through javascript in the resize event. I figured it ought to be possible using only css, or am I wrong..?

2) How do I **vertically center** the menu div, the buttons need to be in the middle of the screen and may not drop off the bottom of the screen. The following didn't work

```
.menu{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    margin:auto auto;
}
```

Comment: @13ruce1337 That has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @ZachSaucier it seems he wants a responsive layout. I could be wrong on what he is questioning. "I figured it ought to be possible using only css, or am I wrong..?"

Comment: The `<center>` tag has been depreciated. Use `margin:0 auto;` or something similar instead. It seems you need to learn [some basics of CSS](http://www.cssbasics.com/)

Comment: Your "new" way has a disadvantage- it doesn't print. I don't think you want that for logos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `img` tag is okay. The `center` tag is obsolete since about 1867. But you can easily use `text-align: center` as a style on the parent element of the logo.

So with a piece of HTML like this:

```
<div class="logo"><img src="..."></div>
```

and a piece of CSS like this:

```
.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
.logo img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

You should have a centered logo of about half the width of the page.

There is no shame in using the `img` tag, and in fact, if you want to scale, then it's very convenient to have this. An image will automatically scale its height relatively according to its width. There is no easy way to get the same effect using just a background image.

Alternatively, you can make the logo a background. But then you'll have to specify the height of the container, because it doesn't have any content at all and will otherwise collapse:

```
.logo {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cwj2b/

Comment: Thanks the proposed img tag solutions works for me, plus the "text-align: center" can also center the buttons horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

For centering the logo with a div:

http://jsfiddle.net/L3mNT/1/

Code:

```
<div class="logo">
   <img width="50%" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo{
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    clear:both;
}

.logo img {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
}
```

For centering the menu items vertically, honestly I doubt that'd be sensible. If the logo height is at least larger than 50% of the screen, it'll cover part of them. You could potentially produce a solution for that, but I'd imagine it'd be quirky regardless.

I think this achieves what you should be aiming for - everything responds nicely. Perhaps some research into `media-query` tags for responsive design in CSS would be a good start for achieving some more desirable in relation to the buttons. I'd suggest increasing or descreasing their size; a mobile device should respond by having smaller buttons than a desktop, for instance.

Also, please try to Google before you answer a question. I'm going to cry if I see another question with the words "CSS" and "div centering" together.

Comment: I went with the "text-align: center", but thanks the "margin-left/right" is a good answer also. My game project will definitely only be used on mobile phones, so no need for media-query I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can *roughly* center the buttons like this:

```
.menu{
    z-index:1;
    background:grey;
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:-2%;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you can center elements more than this

Comment: No, it's not incorrect.  While you can center elements more than this, you can also *roughly* center elements like this.

Comment: Agreed, but you changed your answer *after* my comment

Comment: Thanks this is a good solution but I need a little more control for the desired result. So I was hoping it could be just css but I guess there's no way around using javascript, that is; set the css margin-top/bottom 50% and then update the height in pixels.